# Chrome running on a vm fedora wont load meteor project

Tags: google-chrome, meteor

I've picked up the discover meteor ebook earlier today and have been following the steps. It's been a great experience and I hope I can contribute to this community once I have a more thorough understanding of the technology. All is going well and I was using firefox as my browser. I decided to install chrome since that is the browser I use on my host machine on a day to day basis. However when I load the project up in chrome its a blank screen. The console reports the following(pastebin)

http://pastebin.com/wvEaVNPv
Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: If I load a remote meteor site, it appears to work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

YES!  It comes and goes with time or development, and you will get different results in different browsers (ubuntu).  I currently am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined meteor.js:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined standard-app-packages.js:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined random.js:21
etc
```

A few weeks ago, chrome canary was bad but release chrome not.  It may be some subtle code issue triggers things because as I developed madly but checked intermittently that problem came and went maybe three times, and once another browser gave me a clue on something it didn't like, which also cured chrome.

I don't have any tools/concepts to debug this further.  I initially got through Discover Meteor using chrome about 2 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check your accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown.  If you are using bootstrap-3 you'll need accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.  I found this as one possible cause when I went back.